# Web (ASP.Net) Wcf: Not Found Error connecting from desktop client

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, web-config

I am setting up an ASP.Net WebForms sub-domain with WCF hosted on a shared hosting account. WCF is the primary purpose of the site at the moment. I am having trouble establishing a link from my desktop yielding a perpetual

> Unable to connect to the remote server

I am trying from both `Add Service Reference` and from C#. I want C# code at the end on the client.

I keep playing around with port numbers and different types of bindings, but nothing works.

**Web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MyCloud.Communication.CloudService" behaviorConfiguration="BehaviorMyCloudService">
                <endpoint address=""
                                    binding="wsHttpBinding"
                                    bindingConfiguration="EndpointBindingMyCloudService"
                                    contract="MyCloud.Communication.ICloudService"
                                    behaviorConfiguration="web"
                                    >
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/MyCloudService/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="BehaviorMyCloudService">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                    <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
                        <defaultPorts>
                            <add scheme="http" port="8080" />
                        </defaultPorts>
                    </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding
                    name="EndpointBindingMyCloudService"
                    allowCookies="false"
                    closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                    sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text"
                    textEncoding="utf-8"
                    transactionFlow="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    >
                    <security mode="None">
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
            <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
                <add prefix="http://localhost:8080"/>
            </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**CloudService.svc (C# Code)**:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.Web;

namespace MyCloud.Communication
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class CloudService : ICloudService, IErrorHandler
    {
        public UInt16 GetServiceId()
        {
            return MyCloudLibrary.Constants.My_Id_CloudService;
        }
    }
}
```

**ICloudService.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace MyCloud.Communication
{
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed/*, CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackCloudService)*/)]
    public interface ICloudService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
        [FaultContractAttribute(typeof(CloudServiceFault))]
        UInt16 GetServiceId();
    }
}
```

**Client Side C# Code**:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://Mycloud.asdfmydomain.com/MyCloudService");
var pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICloudService>(binding, endpointAddress);
Program.HostIpcCloudService = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
Program.HostIpcCloudService.Connect();
CommCloudService.IsPipeCloudService = true;
UInt16 serviceId = Program.HostIpcCloudService.GetServiceId();
```

**Client Side C# Error**:

> OuterException:
>
> "There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://mycloud.asdfmydomain.com/MyCloudService that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details."
>
> InnerException:
>
> "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

The `Add Service Reference` from `Visual Studio 2017` said the same thing.

I got similar code working from my Windows Service, so maybe the problem is that I am going cross machine, possibly ports, possibly a firewall on the hosting account, etc.

Some (but not all) references:

- [wcf web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765798/wcf-web-config-file)
- [WCF Web.Config Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070468/wcf-web-config-question)
- [how to programmatically connect a client to a wcf service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943148/how-to-programmatically-connect-a-client-to-a-wcf-service)
- [MS: wcf client overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-client-overview)
- etc., etc.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE BASED ON ANSWER 1:**

(SO should pay me a pain and suffering fee for having to endure this hugely annoying celebration April Fool's theme. I am attempting to focus on programming and stay focused.)

I am making progress, no dice yet.

My no service found error message and duplicated `MyCloud.Communication.MyCloud` rather than `MyCLoud.Communication.CloudService` error message was the result of an incomplete refactoring on the part of Visual Studio. Visual Studio did NOT refactor the .SVC markup file.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyCloud.Communication.CloudService" CodeBehind="CloudService.svc.cs" %>
```

Specifying in a browser the following URL yields:

```
http://mycloud.asdfmydomain.com/Communication/CloudService.svc/Address1
```

Here is a key part of the URL from the Microsoft [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/specifying-an-endpoint-address):

> or you can provide a base address for the ServiceHost of a service and then specify an address for each endpoint associated with this service that is defined relative to this base address.
>   Path: /mathservice.svc/secureEndpoint

I had to remove the commented out `<serviceHostingEnvironment` because the browser wanted `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"`.

The text says that the first part of the URI is the `path to the SVC file` followed by the `endpoint address name` specified in the `EndPointAddres` tag.

**Error Via Chrome:**

```
[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Communication/CloudService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The endpoint at 'http://mycloud.asdfmydomain.com/Communication/CloudService.svc/Address1' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings..]
```

**Error Via C#:**

```
{"The requested service, 'http://mycloud.asdfmydomain.com/Communication/CloudService.svc/Address1' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information."}
```

I am making progress.

Answer (score 0):

In you web.config you write

```
 <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost/MyCloudService/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
```

When you call the service , the address is http://Mycloud.asdfmydomain.com/MyCloudService ,which  mismatches the address configuration in your web.config.

If you are not sure what address your service is, you could see it through wsdl.

For example , my web.config is

```
<service name="Service.CalculatorService" >
    <endpoint address="Calculator.svc/abc/" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="ServiceInterface.ICalculatorService" ></endpoint>
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:62193/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Then when I input address of my service's  wsdl address http://localhost:62193/Calculator.svc?singleWsdl.

I could find address of my service through the wsdl at the bottom.
[image]

You could see even I only write one Calculator.svc , there are still two Calculator.svc.

Because baseaddress will be combined with your svc first and then  combined with relative address.
So  the final address will be  baseaddree + svc + relativeaddress.

Please refer to the link below [WCF: relativeAddress,baseAddress and binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849183/wcf-relativeaddress-baseaddress-and-binding)